# How to get a program's CPU utilization, Memory utilization, and elapsed time from a specific point to another?

Tags: c#, memory, cpu-usage

Take for example I have this particular segment of code in C#:

```
int x;
for(int i=0; i>100; i++)
{
   x=x*i;
}
```

How will I get the CPU Utilization, Memory utilization, and elapsed time, for that process only?

Comment: Take a look at `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a profiler. Getting started for Visual Studio is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx

Note there are different versions of the article for different versions of Visual Studio.

Another offering can be found at http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/?gclid=CIzJ-YyrhbMCFc2R3godRkEAOQ

For the Mono platform you might want to look into the built in profiler: http://www.mono-project.com/Profiler